# Can I use a derived class function if base class is called as parameter?

Tags: c#

I have a class with `public MyClass(Form form)` as constructor

**Is it possible for me to use the functions I made in a class derived from `Form` in this class?** (Named `DerivedClass`)

For now I was thinking, check if `form` is `DerivedClass` then use its functions, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if (form is DerivedClass)
{
    form.DerivedClassFunction();
}
```

Doing this I get the same error :

> "Form" does not contain a definition of "DerivedClassFunction"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1061)

Comment: You need to cast to the real type: `((Derived)form).DerivedClassFunction();`. Or simply use that: `(form as Derived)?.DerivedClassFunction();` ...

Comment: Or `if (form is Derived derived) { derived.DerivedClassFunction(); }`

Comment: whilst the above suggestions work, you should rethink your design. Usually a base-class does not know - and does not *need* to - **anything** about possible derived classes.

Comment: Voting is somewhat unpredictable: don't worry about an isolated downvote or two. Note that your question doesn't contain a [mcve] -- there's nothing I can paste directly into e.g. https://dotnetfiddle.net, and see your problem

Comment: @canton7 Ok I might have overlooked the copy/paste aspect, but thanks for the cheer up and clarification

Comment: I want to echo what @HimBromBeere said above. Any time you have to do this is a huge code smell - please reconsider your approach.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, DavidG yet, I think something is really bad in my design, but saddly I don't think I have the time to restart it to have a better structure. Do you have any tips about how to have a good desgin in my future softwares?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to convert it to your derived type, either via:

```
if (form is Derived)
{
    ((Derived)form).DerivedClassFunction();
}
```

or (new in C# 7):

```
if (form is Derived derived)
{
    derived.DerivedClassFunction();
}
```